# Javascript, adding string to array[string]

Tags: javascript

I have two variables:

```
var cost = new Array();
var maxslot = new Array();
```

and I set the values like this:

```
<script>
cost = {"m2mp":"0.05"};
maxslot = {"m2mp":"1000"};
</script>
<script>
cost = {"samp":"0.04"};
maxslot = {"samp":"500"};
</script>
```

But `samp` replaces `m2mp` and if I call `alert(cost["m2mp"])`, it outputs `undefined` (if I don't assign `samp`, I get the correct output). I tried replacing `=` with `+=`, but it did not help (`samp` and `m2mp` are both `undefined` then).

I couldn't find any solution to "simulate" this:

```
cost["string"] = string;
```

Comment: Why do you even have separate scripts? In one script, you could simply write `cost = {m2mp: 0.05, samp: 0.04); maxslot = {m2mp: 0.04, samp: 500);` I just assumed that the values should be treated as numbers anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this:

```
<script>
    cost["m2mp"] = "0.05";
    maxslot["m2mp"] = "1000";
    cost["samp"] = "0.04";
    maxslot["samp"] = "500";
</script>
```

However, the way you want your variables makes them `Objects`, not `Arrays`. So you'll have to replace:

```
var cost = new Array();
var maxslot = new Array();
```

With:

```
var cost = new Object();
var maxslot = new Object();
```

Or, you could just declare the variables and assign values to it in one line, in a "Object literal":

```
var cost    = {'m2mp':'0.05', 'samp': '0.04'}
var maxslot = {'m2mp':'1000', 'samp': '500'}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second snippet you're creating **objects** (curly braces), not **arrays**. Are you trying to add key-value pairs to your vars?

You should simply set the properties you need:

```
var cost, maxslot;
// ...
cost = {"m2mp":"0.05"};
maxslot = {"m2mp":"1000"};

cost["samp"] = "0.04";
maxslot["samp"] = "500";
```

---

In JavaScript you create a new object using curly braces:

```
var obj = {};
obj.constructor; // function Object() { [native code] }
```

*Side note: `[]` notation is preferred over `new Array()` when creating an array.*

```
var arr = [];
arr.constructor; // function Array() { [native code] }
```